# Symfony Forms - Changing the field class based on available input data

Tags: css, forms, symfony, styles

I would like to add a specific class to a select field based on whether it has information populated from the request or not - in the specific case, it is a filters form which should indicate which filters have been filled in once the form is submitted as an UX feature. I know I can do that directly in twig by checking the `form.fieldname.vars.data` property in twig and setting the class manually but is this the most elegant/easy way to achieve it?

Comment: Do it in twig imho or javascript: keep separate logic from view.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this would be better suited to do while you build the form, so on the PHP side:

```
#determine css class
if($something_or_other) {
    $css_class = 'my_class';
}

$builder->add(
    'input_1',
    ChoiceType::class, #depending on your SF2 version, this will differ
    [
        'attr' => ['class' => $css_class]
    ]
)
```

Comment: So it is best suited inside the form type?

Comment: Personally, I would have some sort of Util class with a method that would do this. This could be called from the controller, and the class could be sent into the form type when you instantiate it.

Comment: The line with comment is simply wrong: if you would like to do this, remove single quotes.

Comment: @DonCallisto - Ah the woes of writing code outside my IDE. You're absolutely right, of course. Edited.